# Sci-fi stories involving a magical element called Fae that would alter reality

Tags: story-identification, novel

I read a trilogy of soft sided Sci Fi books in 1998. No idea when it was published.

They were great stories involving a magical element called Fae that would alter reality, and was influenced by intention. I would like to read it again but can not remember titles or author. Can you help me?

Comment: This is very light on details, although you might be having trouble remembering any more, please check out [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/21267) to see if it helps jog your memory.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/214431/sci-fi-fantasy-book-people-stranded-on-a-planet-where-tech-doesnt-work-magic (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 6):

While there is a paucity of details I believe you may be thinking of the Coldfire trilogy by C.S. Friedman

from a synopsis, For over a thousand years, the colonists of the planet Erna have struggled to gain control over a land prone to seismic instability and infused with a wild, near-sentient natural force known as "the fae." While sorcerers and adepts manipulate the dark and light sides of this power, the Church maintains its stance in opposition to its use. As the dark side of the fae grows in strength, feeding off the nightmares and greed of the minds that are drawn to it, four individuals form an unwilling alliance to battle the source of evil

Comment: Just adding a link to the [books](http://www.csfriedman.com/novels/coldfire-trilogy/)